# Fine-tuning Llama-7B using deepspeed and withholding a GPU

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to fine-tune Llama-7B on a dataset of batch size 1 (so data is not the issue memory wise). I am using deepspeed with huggingface trainer. The issue I am facing is that deepspeed doesn’t let me set the model to a device separately (it does so automatically, causing OOM errors), but as a consequence, executing non-training/forward passes through the model/obtain logits take forever as they run on the CPU.

So what I am trying to do is withhold a GPU so that the model can execute forward calls on that GPU, after allowing deepspeed to modify it.

I have tried using deepspeed --include localhost:(GPUs I want deepspeed to use), but this sets CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to exclude the withheld GPU I want to use, and deepspeed automatically uses all GPUs in --include. Is there any way I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting the `gradient_checkpointing = True` when you are training the parameters.

Comment: note: if you think a question needs more detail/clarity, you are discouraged from answering it until that detail/clarity is added. see [answer].

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Consider taking the [tour].